# Python write to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, urllib2

I have a little problem in a small python script running on a debian server.

First what it should do:
 - Get the list from the server -> working
 - Convert to real string list -> working
 - Write to file -> Does nothing...

Already tried to use the same code in the python interface (>>>) and it writes everything the way it should.
Files are already created and got a chmod 777 on it.
Even checked if not accidentially another instance of that scipt is running which locks the file but nothing ...

Anyone got an idea why it won't write the files when started but in interface?

And now here's the script itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import sys
import time
import re

exitNodes = []
readableNodes = []
class BlockTor():
    def getListFromWeb(myself):
        url = "https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/"
        #url = "file:///E:/test.txt"

        try:
            for line in urllib.request.urlopen(url):
                exitNodes.append(str(line, encoding='utf8'))

            for node in exitNodes:
                readableNodes.append(re.sub('\\n', '', node))
            #print(exitNodes)
            #sys.exit()
        except:
            try:
                f = open("/var/log/torblocker.log", "a")
                #f = open("E:\\logfile.log", "a")
                f.write("[" + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M") + "] Error while loading new tornodes")
                f.close()
            except:
                print("Can't write log")
                pass
            sys.exit()
            pass


    def buildList(myself):
        f = open("/etc/apache2/torlist/tor-ip.conf", "w")
        #f = open ("E:\\test-ips.conf", "w")
        f.write('<RequireAll>\n')
        f.write('   Require all granted\n')
        for line in readableNodes:
            f.write('   Require not ip ' + line + '\n')
        f.write('</RequireAll>')
        f.close()
        try:
            f = open("/var/log/torblocker.log", "a")
            #f = open("E:\\logfile.log", "a")
            f.write("[" + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M") + "] Sucessfully updated tor blacklist")
            f.close()
        except:
            pass


    def torhandler(myself):
        BlockTor.getListFromWeb(myself)
        BlockTor.buildList(myself)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asdf = BlockTor()
    BlockTor.torhandler(asdf)
```

EDIT:
Forgot to mention - If you want to test it be careful: This server allows only one request each 30minutes

Comment: Please do not use naked `except:` clauses. They are likely hiding an exception you're getting.

Comment: Indeed- I know that the `except` clauses are supposed to be set up to write to log files, but try commenting out all the `except` clauses and just see what happens

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To concatenate strings, use the `+` operator. `&` is the [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_AND#AND) - calling it with two strings will result in a `TypeError`:

```
>>> "[" & ""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

Your blanket `except` suppresses that error. Replace

```
try:
    f = open("/var/log/torblocker.log", "a")
    #f = open("E:\\logfile.log", "a")
    f.write("[" & time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M") & "] Sucessfully updated tor blacklist")
    f.close() # ^                                     ^
except:
    pass
```

with

```
with open("/var/log/torblocker.log", "a") as torf:
    torf.write("[" + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M") + "] " +
               "Sucessfully updated tor blacklist")
```

If you want to ignore the exception when the file can't be written to, surround that with `try .. except IOError:`.

Comment: Thanks for that hint (already saw it but you posted before i could exit my question).

But the problem still exits, even with the replaced "&" chars and the function of you (with open...) it DOESN'T write to it. 

No error given but simply nothing in the logfile or the blacklist

Comment: Most likely, you don't have sufficient access rights to the file in question. Try removing the `try..except` and see what error you get. If you're not sure about the error, post a new question with it.

Comment: That was the solution. I forgot to set the access rights to the output file so it was unable to write into it

Answer (score 2):

```
f.write("[" & time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M") & "] Error while loading new tornodes")
```

is a `TypeError`.  To concatentate strings, use `+`, not `&`.  Here you catch the `TypeError` in your bare `except` statement.  This demonstrates why bare `except` statements are typically not a good idea.  In general, only handle the errors that you expect and know how to handle properly.

You could also use string formatting:

```
f.write('[{0}] Error while loading new tornodes'.format(time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M")))
```